# Endpoint reference for the Operation not found error

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, firewall, wsdl.exe

I used this wsdl file : http://ihexds.nist.gov:9080/tf6/services/xdsrepositoryb?wsdl
to generate a proxy C# code file using wsdl.exe. Exact command is

> "wsdl /o:D:\NIST_stuff /l:CS /protocol:SOAP12
>   http://ihexds.nist.gov:9080/tf6/services/xdsrepositoryb?wsdl"

Now, I need to invoke the operation named "ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequest". From the WSDL you can see that the operation takes a "ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequestRequest" and returns a "ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequestResponse" :

```
<wsdl:operation name="ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequest">
<wsdl:input message="ns2:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequestRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:ihe:iti:2007:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSet-b"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns2:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequestResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequestResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I know what the SOAP request xml should look like and I have an application that prepares that XML. I am hoping for some way to pass that XML as the request body.

But in the proxy class generated, the code for the operation invocation looks like this:

```
public void ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequest() {
        this.Invoke("ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequest", new object[0]);}
```

When i call the method like this :

```
            WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("x.x.x.x:80", true);

            xdsrepositoryb xdsrepositoryb = new xdsrepositoryb();
            xdsrepositoryb.Proxy = webProxy;
            xdsrepositoryb.ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequest();
```

I get error :

> The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is
>   http://ihexds.nist.gov:9080/tf6/services/xdsrepositoryb and the WSA
>   Action =

Any hints whats wrong ? Im a first timer with web services.

Answer (score 0):

if you look closely there is only input/output for http binding not soap 1.1/1.2.

So you will only be able to call the ws with a httprequest and addxml in the body yourself.

Comment: can you look at the additional description i just added ("Further narrow down/simplifying experiment :") which is similar simplified scenario i managed to reproduce

Comment: Hi If you look you adding service reference(wcf) not a webservice reference WCF works a little diff. if you want to do it the old way after you click add service reference there is a advance button and in the web service button. here is a link http://kennyw.com/work/indigo/106

Comment: Yes i also tried via the way you said : " add service reference there is a advance button and in the web service button" but that too has same problem.

Comment: Ok but like i say in the beginning the WSDL looks like it only accept http request not soap specific. It has bindings for soap but the webmethods does not have arguments.

Comment: So are you saying that this is incomplete:   <wsdl:operation name="ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequest">
<soap12:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

Comment: I am first timer at using webservices, so im not clear how to "call the ws with a httprequest and addxml in the body yourself"

Comment: yes who ever did this webservice did not add parameters for the soap endpoint